# three.js ellipse.setRotationFromAxisAngle eliminates existing quaternion

Tags: three.js, rotation

I'm currently working on a three.js project.

One of the tasks is to rotate the ellipse around the **local x axis** and **z axis** for **rx** and **rz** degrees; and then rotate along **a global axis (0,1,0)** for **ry** degrees.
My code is this:

```
    function createOrbit(ax, xRadius, yRadius, rx, ry, rz){
    const curve = new THREE.EllipseCurve(
        ax, 0,              // ax, aY
        xRadius, yRadius,         // xRadius, yRadius
        0,  2 * Math.PI,  // aStartAngle, aEndAngle
        false,            // aClockwise
        0                // aRotation
    );
    const points = curve.getPoints( 50 );
    const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints( points );
    const material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color : 0xffff00 } );
    // Create the final object to add to the scene
    const ellipse = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
    ellipse.rotation.x += rx;
    ellipse.rotation.z += rz;
    yax = new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0);
    ellipse.setRotationFromAxisAngle(yax, ry);

    return ellipse;
}
```

However, I found that the function `ellipse.setRotationFromAxisAngle(yax, ry)` will eliminates the existing and reintroduce a new set of quarternion introduced by

```
    ellipse.rotation.x += rx;
    ellipse.rotation.z += rz;
```

Any advice how I could solve this?

Comment: three.js provides all the `Object3D` methods you should need: `rotateOnAxis()`, `rotateOnWorldAxis()`, `rotateX()`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that happens because any method called `.set()` naturally overrides whatever the previous state was. What you need to do is access the `Quaternion` (which is a mathematical object where all rotations are calculated) and multiply it by a new one:

```js
ellipse.rotation.x += rx;
ellipse.rotation.z += rz;

// Create new rotation object
const yQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
yQuaternion.setFromAxisAngle(yax, ry);

// Multiply the ellipse's rotation with the y-axis rotation
ellipse.quaternion.multiply(yQuaternion);
```

You can read more about quaternions here: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Quaternion

Comment: Thank you for your advice! That works nicely. The quaternion thingy is often overlooked by me.